# Selenium Element not Visible Exception : Despite Using Correct XPATH and Putting Breakpoint to Wait for Element to Be Displayed in HTML

Tags: selenium

`$x("//input[contains(@id,'default-column')]")` - returns 10 elements

```
public List<WebElementFacade> defaultFieldsCheckBox;
```

`$x("(//input[contains(@id,'default-column')])[1]")` - returns 1 element

```
public WebElementFacade firstFieldsCheckBox;
```

- "Customize Click" Opens List Of Check-boxes
- Check Boxes are Displayed in View after "Customize Click"
- I even put a breakpoint after "Customize Click" to ensure the Check-boxes are displayed (see image)
- mpAuthPage.firstFieldsCheckBox.isDisplayed() 
  throws ElementNotVisibleException: Element not available
- mpAuthPage.defaultFieldsCheckBox.size()
  throws NoSuchElementException: Element not Visible
- firstFieldsCheckBox can be found by XPATH and is clearly displayed in HTML
- defaultFieldsCheckBox.size() should return 10 instead of error Element not 
  Visible
- Any Ideas as to my issue ??

[Checkbox Display In HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3hW6.png)

[Image Of HTML Added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdSzY.png)

Comment: Please include the html source.

Comment: You are asking us to debug your issue blind. We need to see the relevant HTML and the locators you are using for the different fields you referenced in your question. Have you checked to see if there is an IFRAME?

Comment: Image Of HTML Added

Comment: If they are in a different frame, you need to switch to that frame before interacting with the elements, see JeffC's comment. It's not visible on your image If there is an additional iframe.

Comment: I can interact with all the immediate surrounding elements to the checkbox => so that to me rules out the iframe possibility been the problem. Furthermore the checkbox are not contained in iframe.

Comment: All this HTML is displayed in images provided. I have absolutely no idea of why this is happening, I even tried to directly click and interact using JS executer after putting breakpoint, so as it would definitely be displayed - and still, element not visible exception 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually kind of tricky. The custom-checkbox class makes the checkbox input itself hidden so it can't be interacted with.

You should instead try to click on the *label* like

```
//label[text() = '{Text of Label}']
```

You could also target them by the `for` attribute to get all of them in one shot like this

```
//label[contains(@for, 'default-column')]
```

Edit: Based on your comment, I got around this by

```
@driver.find_element(:xpath, "//label[contains(text(), '{label text}')]/preceding::input[1]").attribute("checked")
```

That's ruby code. You didn't mention explicitly which language you're working with (I don't recognize it), but you should be able to convert it over fairly easily.

Comment: Actually this is the current implementation, the checkbox label is used to fire the click. But that logic breaks down when you call isSelected ( ) on that label , it always returns false, as it’s not an input/checkbox which is why I am trying to use the actual input checkbox as the primary element (s) to interact with

Comment: WebElement input = mpTranPage.defaultFieldsCheckBox.get(i).findElement(By.xpath("preceding::input[1]"));
    String isChecked = input.getAttribute("checked");
    System.out.println("Checkbox " + getText(mpTranPage.defaultFieldsCheckBox.get(i)) + " Is Checked  " + isChecked);

Comment: Thanks scilence this worked and this is the solution !

WebElement input = mpTranPage.defaultFieldsCheckBox.get(i).findElement(By.xpath("preceding::input[1]"));
    
String isChecked = input.getAttribute("checked"); 
   
System.out.println("Checkbox " + getText(mpTranPage.defaultFieldsCheckBox.get(i)) + " Is Checked  " + isChecked);

Comment: @Mark glad I could help. Just had to deal with this same issue after a bootstrap upgrade on our app.

Answer (score 0):

The Question was answered by scilence - Thank you !!

Thanks scilence this worked and this is the solution !

WebElement input = mpAuthPage.defaultFieldsCheckBox.get(i).findElement(By.xpath("preceding::input[1]"));

String isChecked = input.getAttribute("checked");

System.out.println("Checkbox " + getText(mpAuthPage.defaultFieldsCheckBox.get(i)) + " Is Checked  " + isChecked);